# Paypal Button returns 'Order could not be captured'

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am using paypal Buttons SDK.  The Code activating the button is:-

```
        paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: ( data, actions ) => {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: this.amount.toFixed(2),
                        currency_code: "GBP",
                    }
                }]
            })
        },
        onApprove: ( data, actions ) => {
            return actions.order.capture().then(details => {
              console.log('details',details);
            })
        },
        onError: ( error ) => {
            console.log('error',error);
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container')
```

The User Interface operates as expected, there is then a long pause before the error is returned.  The client_id used in the script tag is for a sandbox account.  I can find not documentation describing possible cause for the error...

`error Error: Order could not be captured`

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Paypal.. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#1-get-paypal-rest-api-credentials

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comment try to do a curl with this URL :

*https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/api/order/ODER_ID/capture*

And it replies with code 401 and did some research and end up finding that I was using a wrong account to make payments.

I refresh the PayPal login and login with the correct sandbox buyer account and make the payment and It works.

Probably paypal should give correct errors messages.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check using CURL which returns the Paypal server?
This is a comment but I do not have 50pkt S / O. Sorry.

Comment: This is the paypal server POST which is failing... [link] www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/api/order/3J674917081315435/capture ( The url has https://www. at the front, but for some reason this is not appearing in the comment )

Comment: curl -v -X POST https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/api/order/3J674917081315435/capture

Maybe 401 unauthorised?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the connection is authorised, If I change the client_id in the script tag to nonsense the session fails to start ( window.paypal is undefined ).  Also there's a fair bit of interaction which occurs prior to the final stage ( processing the order ).

Comment: > POST /smart/api/order/3J674917081315435/capture HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Tue, 12 Mar 2019 22:51:43 GMT
< Server: Apache
..... more....

Comment: If I curl -v -X POST www.sandbox.paypal.com/smart/api/order/3J674917081315435/capture the response I get is HTTP/1.0 302 Found ?

Answer (score 0):

If you get a Xss message in the console, just try in private navigation, disconnect from your paypal buyer account.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same "Order could not be captured" error at "actions.order.capture()" in the *onApprove* callback.

In my case, it worked on the first run but not the subsequent calls. I found my order always had the same invoice_id. I removed invoice_id and Paypal stopped complaining.

It should be good if the invoice_id was always unique.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem with Nuxt , checkout works but catch error response : Error 500 order-could-not-be-captured

```
<template>
  <no-ssr>
    <v-layout row wrap>  
      <div ref="paypal"></div>   
    </v-layout>
  </no-ssr>
</template>
```

Script

```js
mounted() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
      "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MyKeyID";
    script.addEventListener("load", this.setLoaded);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  },
  methods: {
    setLoaded: function() {
      this.loaded = true;
      window.paypal
        .Buttons({
          createOrder: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [
                {
                  description: "Test description",
                  amount: {
                    currency_code: "USD",
                    value: 1
                  }
                }
              ]
            });
          },
          onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
            const order = await actions.order.capture();
            this.paidFor = true;
            console.log(order);
          },
          onError: err => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        })
        .render(this.$refs.paypal);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add more description to your answer? or it's another question?

Comment: Is this another question?